# .net (my.settings) new "magic" folder created for user.config file after system crash (power failure)

Tags: .net, application-settings

this is my first question here, so please let me know if I do anything wrong.

My problem is this:

I have an application (winform .net) running at a client. The application is working fine, and i'm using application settings to store a couple of variables needed for the system.

Now, 2 times in the last couple of months, our client has had a powerfailure, and each time this happens:

1. Our application doesn't start, because we check for the settings
2. We go in and look in appdata/local/companyname/ and find a new folder is created for our app, with a new random ID after the app name.

example directory structure before crash:
C:\Users\ClientUser\AppData\Local\Our Company\OurProduct5305069390305

after crash:
C:\Users\ClientUser\AppData\Local\Our Company\OurProduct5305069390305
C:\Users\ClientUser\AppData\Local\Our Company\OurProduct9882589003822

and now suddenly, the new directory seems to be the one that's used by our app.

3. The new "magically" created folder has a user.config file, but it is empty. And this is where our app now points for some reason I have no idea of.

Copying over the user.config file from the "old" application folder to the newly created one returns everything to normal.

Any ideas why our application creates a new folder id after a hard crash? 
How could I prevent this the next time their power runs out?

Any tips appreciated!

Update: We since moved away from using the built in settings, and are using custom config-files now, never had a problem since the switch!

Comment: Did some windows updates run after booting up the machine after the power failure?  It's possible that could be the source of your problem.

Comment: 1) Is this a "ClickOnce application"? 2) Do the new folder exist _before_ you launch the application (after the crash)?

Comment: Timothy:
No windows updates ran after booting up.

Bjørn-Roger:
1) No, it is not
2) I unfortunely cannot confirm that the folder existed before the launch.

My thoughts so far is that maybe the application is trying to restore from the crash, and I don't know how to set default my.settings values for restore.